# How to calcul tangente with Bokeh callback custom JS?

Tags: python-3.x, math, plot, bokeh

I have to make a graphic with a function, his derivative and the tangent.
I'm exercising on python with Bokeh library.

I've tried multiple different calcul to get the tangent. To change the variables,function but without any success.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource

#First Curve
x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
a = -10
y = (x**3)-12*x


#fonction
def f(x):
    return ((x**3)-12*x)
def fprime(x):
    return ((3*x**2)-12)
yprime = fprime(x)
#prepare list of value for tan
ytan = []
yprimetan = []
tan = []
for a in range (-25,25):
    y1 = f(a)
    y2= fprime(a)
    y3 = y1 * a + y2
    ytan.append(y1)
    yprimetan.append(y2)
    tan.append(y3)

print('liste y ',ytan)
print('liste yprime ',yprimetan)
print('liste tan ',tan)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y=ytan))
plot = figure(y_range=(-50, 50), plot_width=800, plot_height=800)

plot.line('x','y', source=source, line_width=3,legend= 'Fonction', line_alpha=0.6)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var A = amp.value;
    var B = offset.value;
    var x = data['x']
    var y = data['y']
    for (var i = -10; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = B + A *((x[i]**3)-12*x[i]);
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")


amp_slider = Slider(start=-10, end=10, value=1, step=.1,
                    title="Amplitude", callback=callback)
callback.args["amp"] = amp_slider

offset_slider = Slider(start=-10, end=10, value=0, step=.1,
                       title="Offset", callback=callback)

callback.args["offset"] = offset_slider

#Second Curve dérivé

source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=yprimetan))
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source2, line_width=3,legend= 'Dérivé', line_alpha=0.6,color='red')

#Third Curve Tan
source3 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,tan=tan,yprime=yprimetan,y=tan))
plot.line('x','tan', source=source3,legend= 'Tangente', line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6,color='green')
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source3), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var Z = tangente.value;
    var y = data['y']
    var yprime = data['yprime']
    var tan = data['tan']
    var x = data['x']
    for (var i = -10; i < x.length; i++) {
        tan[i] = yprime[i] * (x[i]-Z) + y[i] ;
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

#tan[i]= (3*(x[i]**2)-12) * (Z-x[i]) + ((x[i]**3)-12*x[i])
tan_slider = Slider(start=-10, end=10, value=1, step=.1,
                    title="Tangente", callback=callback)
callback.args["tangente"] = tan_slider
#Output

layout = row(
    plot,
    widgetbox(amp_slider, offset_slider,tan_slider),
)
output_file("slider.html", title="slider.py example")

show(layout)
```

I expect to have a tangent that i can move through the curve.
You can execute the code to see the graphic i have for the moment.